# "call it quit" or "called it quit"

Tags: tense, idioms

*Think its about time Tomas **call it quit**. His body can't take it anymore and he's 35.*

Do you think that the bold part of the text is grammatically OK? Isn't it a better choice "called it quit" as in:  It’s time we went home  – The text comes from a Twitter post.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "called it quit" as in: It's time we went home? Is "It's time we went home" only a part of a quote that includes the quit phrase?

Comment: The structure "it's (about) time".

Answer (score 6):

The idiom you are looking for is

> **call it quits**

which has the meaning **to stop**

> Think it's about time Tomas **calls it quits**

It's time for Tomas to **stop** doing something (must be extreme since 35 is still fairly young age)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why is "Think it's about time Tomas calls it quits" and not "Think it's about time Tomas called it quits". What is thedifference between this sentence and this one: It’s time we went home

Comment: Because of the phrase **it's time** you can use the **past tense**. **It's time we called your Mom** means something should have been done but hasn't yet. **We called your Mom** is just **simple past**, something already done. Both **calls** and **called** can be used in your sentences. If you were to say **Let's called it quits** it would be incorrect.  The reason is that **It's time** points to a set time (now) when something hypothetical should have happened (subjunctive).

Comment: The construction *It's time [subject + verb]* is ***always*** used with the verb in the ***past*** tense. Thus it has to be *[I think] it's about time Tomas **called** it quits*.

Comment: @Fumble - I'm not so sure about [always](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+calls+it+quits%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: @J.R.: I did wonder about that, but I couldn't think of any context where *it's about time [something happens]* would be idiomatically "valid" with present tense. Can you?

Comment: **It's time we call it a day and have a beer**(?)

Comment: Based on questions I've seen and examples by *native speakers*, I think that the old rule/description of the past tense form after *it's time* is no longer the only acceptable/valid form. Usages such as **It's time we take a break** as much as I cringe at it, seem on the rise.

Answer (score 0):

[According the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time):

> We can use the expression *it's time* + subject + past verb form to refer to the present moment:
>
> > *Gosh! It’s almost midnight. **It's time we went** home.*
> >
> > Not: <s>It's time we go home</s>.
>
> *It's time* with a verb in the *to*-infinitive form can refer to the speaker and the listener together:
>
> > *Come on. **It's time to start** packing. We have to leave in two hours.* (or ***It's time we started** packing.*)

Adding *about* doesn't change the rest of the grammar, so what the Cambridge Dictionary says still stands. Specifically we can't use *call* or *calls* here. To be grammatically correct (which is not the most important part of a tweet) it would have had to be:

> Think it's about time Tomas **called** it quits. His body can't take it anymore and he's 35.

Note: *quits* is always plural in this idiom.

Of course, not all native speakers adhere to the same set of rules. There may be some for whom the present indicative (i.e. *call/calls*) is perfectly fine.